Unresolved reference: R and BuildConfig in React Native Android Project with Kotlin
I'm currently working on a React Native project with Kotlin and I'm facing some issues during the build process in Android Studio. Specifically, I'm encountering Unresolved reference: R and Unresolved reference: BuildConfig errors in my Kotlin files.
React Native version: 0.74.3
Kotlin version: 1.9.23
Gradle version: 8.6
Android Studio version: Latest
my MainActivity.kt


  package com.thediamlaundry.diamapp

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate

import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Set the theme to AppTheme BEFORE onCreate to support
    // coloring the background, status bar, and navigation bar.
    // This is required for expo-splash-screen.
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(null)
  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "main"

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the [ReactActivityDelegate]. We use [DefaultReactActivityDelegate]
   * which allows you to enable New Architecture with a single boolean flags [fabricEnabled]
   */
  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate {
    return ReactActivityDelegateWrapper(
          this,
          BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED,
          object : DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
              this,
              mainComponentName,
              fabricEnabled
          ){})
  }

  /**
    * Align the back button behavior with Android S
    * where moving root activities to background instead of finishing activities.
    * @see <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()">onBackPressed</a>
    */
  override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
          if (!moveTaskToBack(false)) {
              // For non-root activities, use the default implementation to finish them.
              super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
          }
          return
      }

      // Use the default back button implementation on Android S
      // because it's doing more than [Activity.moveTaskToBack] in fact.
      super.invokeDefaultOnBackPressed()
  }
}
  

My MainApplication.kt


 package com.thediamlaundry.diamapp

import android.app.Application
import android.content.res.Configuration

import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader

import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = ReactNativeHostWrapper(
        this,
        object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
          override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> {
            // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
            // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            return PackageList(this).packages
          }

          override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = ".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"

          override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

          override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
          override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }
  )

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = ReactNativeHostWrapper.createReactHost(applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this)
  }

  override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onConfigurationChanged(this, newConfig)
  }
}  




While building the AAB from the android studio because i have already used free tier from the expo.


 I got this error > Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainActivity.kt:18:14 Unresolved reference: R
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainActivity.kt:35:11 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainApplication.kt:31:60 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainApplication.kt:33:52 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainApplication.kt:34:51 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///Users/pratikbhattarai/Documents/GitHub/diamFrontend/diamApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/thediamlaundry/diamapp/MainApplication.kt:44:9 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig 



I have alredy tried gradle sync. Already used ./gradlew clean command. it gives me build successfull but when i tried to build the project it gives me this error. I have already checked all the dependency and thinks everything is correct and compatible. But at the time of building i am getting this error

Just import missing references.

I simply solved my problem using the following line in the app-level build.gradle:
namespace = "com.thediamlaundry.diamapp"

Initially, it was just:
namespace = "com.diamapp"

After changing this line, my issue was solved.
